# How to accept list as input to REST API build in python

Tags: python, rest, api

I am launching REST API build in python. I wanted to know how I could input a list.
I would like to input couple of names and birth date. 
Example of input: `[‘James’, 2015-02-01], [‘Robert’, 2020-01-01], [‘Prince’, 2001-12-01]`
Rest end point is : our.api.com/birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple query parameters with the same name:

```
your.api.com/birth?name=James&date=2015-02-01&name=Robert&date=2020-01-01
```

In Flask, for example, you could retrieve them as follows:

```
from Flask import request

@app.route('/birth')
def birth():
    names = request.form.getlist('name')
    dates = request.form.getlist('date')
```

Comment: It should be, but you'll have to use some kind of web framework anyway. Still, the API is more about the URI, not the actual implementation, so this approach is independent of your web server/framework/OS